# What results for $1 + 2 + 3 + ...$ are known?

Tags: number-theory

Euler obtained the famous result $1+2+3+...= -1/12$. Is this the only result for $\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}n$ or have other results been derived, for instance in set theory?

Comment: Please do not call this a "result".  It is (by itself) simply false.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: This IS a result. This equality cannot be "true" or  "false" until LHS is DEFINED. With the LHS properly defined, one can compute it. The more precise version of the question would be "what are the reasonable DEFINITIONS of 1+2+3+... which have been proposed?" .

Comment: $\sum n$ is perfectly defined, it is most certainly not the definition of analytic continuation of the Riemann zeta function. Saying that $\sum n = -1/12$ is a bit misleading. In particular it is not Euler's result.

Comment: @Slereah: I am surprised with your statement that 1+2+3... is perfectly defined. May I ask you how? What is your "perfect definition"?

Comment: It is defined as a divergent series in $\Bbb N^\Bbb N$

Comment: Divergent series does not have a sum. You have to DEFINE a sum of some class of divergent series, and then find the sum of this particular series according to your definition. This is what I am trying to explain. Euler defined this sum as $\zeta(-1)$ and then found $\zeta(-1)$. This was his result.

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko: One is free in defining the sum of divergent series. I for my part, for instance, define always: sum div series = nonsense. Well Euler is more influential than me. But if he or anybody else defines something along these lines then he is obliged to distinguish it from the + as it is understood by 99.99 % of mankind.

Comment: @Claus: "well Euler is more influential than me" (and this applies to 99.9% of mankind). Very true! I agree.

Comment: Google "divergent series", to find out that this is an important part of modern mathematics.

Comment: @Claus No, they are only obliged to show that their definition agrees with the usual one for convergent series. [Summation of divergent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Theorems_on_methods_for_summing_divergent_series) is a standard term, so you may find yourself in the 0.01%, at least among mathematicians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me explain that Euler in fact obtained this result since some comments to the original question seem to doubt that.

Leonhard Euler applied the $\zeta$ series to obtain the result, $\zeta(-1) = -1/12$ but he knew that summation of divergent series is doubtful, namely "the cause of great dissent among mathematicians of whom some deny and others affirm that such a sum can be found." See Ed Sandifer: How Euler did it. http://eulerarchive.maa.org/hedi/HEDI-2006-06.pdf

In fact Euler applied the series where it does not converge at all and hence does not converge to $-1/12$ either. But at his times a lot of undigested math was en vogue. So he assumed with Leibniz and the Bernoullis that $1-1+1-1+1-+... = 1/2$ and with Wallis that $1/3 < 1/2 < 1/1 < 1/0 < 1/-1$. All that is wrong. Obviously $1+2+3+...> 1$. And if something else is meant by "$+$", then it should be clearly indicated. Unfortunately Ramanujan and many modern mathematicians accept this confusing notation. On the other hand, Euler has obtained correct results from wrong assumptions like $ log2\infty - log\infty= log2 $ or $(1 + x/\infty)^\infty = e^x$.

Bernard Bolzano in his Paradoxien des Unendlichen, p. 44f denotes the sum of all natural numbers by $S^0$. Further he introduces $N^0$ what we would call the cardinal number today, taking one unit for every natural number. He claims that some (without quoting names) have put $N^0(N^0+1)/2 = S^0$. But he does not endorse this result. He only claims that the sum $S^0$ must be by far larger than $N^0$. If I remember correctly, Euler somewhere wrote $i(i+1)/2$ with $i$ for *numerus infinitus* as he often did. But I am not sure.

Cantor summed all natural numbers with the result $ 1 + 2 + 3 + ... \nu... = \omega$ in a letter of 1883 to Mittag Leffler (i.e., before he had introduced cardinal numbers). He obtained the same sum for the harmonic series. He emphasized however the order of the terms: $2 + 3 + ... + \nu+ ... + 1 = \omega + 1$. Whether $2$ is necessary as first term of the sequence is left open but obviously it is not necessary. For another order he states $1 + 3 + 5 +  ... + (2\nu + 1) + ... + 2 + 4 + 6 + ... + (2\nu) + ... = 2\omega$

Comment: The question was not how Euler obtained this but what are the alternative definitions which lead to a different result.

Comment: I know, but there are comments doubting that Euler derived this result. If the first part collects some more downvotes then I will delete it.